# Remove outliers while preserving the timestamps in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, outliers

I have data in a dataframe in the format shown below:

```
metric  timestamp              cas_pre        fl_rat       ...
0       2017-04-06 11:25:00    687.982849     1627.040283    ...
1       2017-04-06 11:30:00    693.427673     1506.217285    ...
2       2017-04-06 11:35:00    692.686310     1537.114807    ...
....
45      2017-04-06 11:35:00    51987.427673   1537.114807    ...
....
101003  2017-04-06 11:35:00    692.686310     1537.114807    ...
```

It's very clear that row 45 needs to be eliminated since it's an anomaly. There are multiple columns and quite a few rows (100,000+). Now I want to remove the outliers from this, and have been using the code:

```
drop_df = df.drop(columns=['timestamp'])
drop_df = drop_df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(drop_df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

However, this would give me the data without the timestamps. This is due to the fact that I cannot use timestamps within the z-score calculation. However, I want to preserve the timestamps, the correlation to which is completely lost over the filtering with the z-score. This is shown below:

```
metric  timestamp              cas_pre        fl_rat       ...
0       2017-04-06 11:25:00    687.982849     1627.040283    ...
1       2017-04-06 11:30:00    693.427673     1506.217285    ...
2       2017-04-06 11:35:00    692.686310     1537.114807    ...
....
101003  2017-04-06 11:35:00    692.686310     1537.114807    ...
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to explicitly set which columns to use for the z-score calculation:

```
cols = ['cas_pre', 'fl_rat', ...]
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df[cols])) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

Alternatively, you can drop the timestamp column only in the input to the z-score calculation:

```
drop_df = df.drop(columns=['timestamp'])
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(drop_df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: I just tried the second method and it worked. Perfect!